# What is the proper way to detect MySQL "Timeout expired" error in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I want to have a special case in my app for "Timeout expired" exceptions thrown by Data.MySqlClient. What is the better way of detecting them, than checking exception's "Message" property?

I tried checking exception's "Number" property for value 2013 (the only one I found by googling) but it doesn't seem to work in all cases. Edit: did some additional debugging and found out, that sometimes (namely, when timeout happens on client side) Number == 0 (this number can as well mean any client-side error).

My current code looks like this:

```cs
// connection is defined as new MySqlConnection
using(var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel))
{
    try
    {
        using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.Transaction = transaction;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (transaction != null && connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
        log?.ErrorFormatExt(
                            "An error occurred during query execution. All changes canceled.{1}{0}{1}{2}", ex, Environment.NewLine,
                            query); // log is log4net.ILog.
        if (ex is MySqlException mySqlException && mySqlException.Number == TIMEOUT_NUMBER)// const int TIMEOUT_NUMBER = 2013
        {
          // Do special case stuff. Some nasty legacy code you surely don't want to see.
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I sometimes see the log entry (with "Timeout expired" text, of course), but don't see any special case stuff done. Though it is possible that the problem is in the "special case stuff" part, right now I want to be sure I'm doing the checking part the right way.

Comment: Try switching to https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/. It has the same API as MySqlData, but (AFAIK) consistently uses `MySqlErrorCode.TimeoutExpired` for timeout exceptions.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger , unfortunately I cannot do this due to my company's code conventions: we have a strict list of libraries which we are permitted to use and adding a new one just for a single case isn't an option.

Comment: If you need a list of reasons to switch libraries, take a look at https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#fixed-bugs
Maybe there are other problems you've been running into that could be fixed by switching. Particularly if you want to use async in your projects, your company should strongly consider switching since Oracle's Connector/NET has no async support at all.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger, the main problem of MySqlConnector library (as of 2019-10-09) is the lack of major releases (latest version is 0.59.2) which means one can be very cautious about using it on production.